# How can I let my customer select a plan with the Stripe Billing Portal?

Tags: stripe-payments

[image]

This is what my customer sees when I redirect to the portal. But I want them to be able to select a plan and add a payment method themselves.

This is how I'm getting the URL:

```
  const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
    customer: req.body.stripeCustomerId,
    return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/app',
  });
```

I want the user to be able to select a plan, which I have as a `Product`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, the BillingPortal does not support subscribing to *new* Prices/Plans. It only supports switching Prices/Plans (e.g. downgrading or upgrading) or updating quantities purchased: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/customer-portal

You would have to use Stripe Checkout to start your user on a Subscription, and then leverage BillingPortal to allow them to switch Prices.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Stripe Pricing Table instead of only Stripe Checkout

See: https://stripe.com/docs/no-code/pricing-table